# What is the data format called when sets of four hexadecimal characters (in 8 columns)?

Tags: terminology

What is data in the following format called:

[image]

I guess this is a string representation of some lower level data store. I'm not sure what it would be called though.

Comment: It isn't called anything in particular. It's just the obvious way to dump out data in hex, 16 bits at a time.